# React onChange event takes 2 arguments, but even after I write them, an error is thrown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got a problem with my React / typescript code. I have a custom Input, which has its own described property 'onChange'

```
onChange?: (value?: string, event?: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void;
```

And i have a code here

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

<FormField size={"s"}>
  <Input
    className="input__control"
    name=""
    type="text"
    label="Отображаемое название"
    value={title}
    onChange={(value: string, event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setTitle(event.target.value);
    }}
  />
</FormField>
```

But still im getting an error:

> TS2322: Type '(value: string, event: ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(value?: string | undefined, event?: ChangeEvent | undefined) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

If someone can help with my little problem, i would be very happy. Thanks ^.^

Comment: The signatures don't match. Your `onChange` takes two optional arguments, while the function you provide takes two required arguments. Change the signature of `onChange` or pass a function that takes optional arguments.

Comment: Your hook useState define a `title` variable of string type. Check if `event.target.value` may be undefined type. In this case define the hook in this way: `useState<string | undefined>('')`

Comment: You always want to define function props with required arguments.  You aren't required to use them! But you want to know that they are always present. `onChange?: (value: string, event: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void;`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
const onChange = (data?: string, event?: Event) => {
      const { value } = event?.target as unknown as { value: string };
};
  
<input type='radio' onChange={onChange} />
```

And the squeegee lines will go away.